# How to use neocomplete in ftplugin

Tags: vimrc, plugin-neocomplete

I want to use the plugin neocomplete only for a few filetypes.
For example for Go programming language. So I have the following entries in my *~/.vimrc/ftplugin/go.vim*:

```
...
let g:neocomplete#enable_at_startup = 1
let g:neocomplete#enable_smart_case = 1
let g:neocomplete#sources#syntax#min_keyword_length = 3
...
```

*(My plugins are managed through VimPlug which works flawless.)*

Now I have one problem and one question.

**Question:**
Is it bad practice to set global variables in an ftplugin? And why? They seem to work with the exception of the *neocomplete#enable_at_startup* variable.

**Here it comes to the problem:**
neocomplete doesn't do auto-completion until I enable it manually:

```
:NeoCompleteEnable
```

I have to add the following line in my *go.vim* to enable it automatically at startup:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NeoCompleteEnable
```

My question and my problem seem to affect each other. Is there a better way to enable neocomplete plugin only for specific filetypes and to set also different values to the variables for each type?

Greetings

Philipp

Comment: As you've guessed, setting global variables from a ftplugin is a bad practice. According the documentation I've just read, this plugin doesn't seems to be written to work only in specified buffers. It may be best to directly contact the author if you want to activate the plugin only with specific filetypes or in specific projects.

Comment: You could may try to duplicate in your ftplugin the lines from the plugin that register `autocmd CursorHold,InsertEnter` but only for the current buffer (as ftplugins are executed once per related buffer). Note that you may want a `augroup` name built for the current buffer, or to maintain a list of buffers for which the completions is enabled. But this later solution should be implement in the plugin, IMO.

Comment: Do you know if there is an other plugin for completion which plays well with buffers?

Comment: Sorry. I don't use this type of plugin.